# TableViewCell isn't fully displayed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

My TableViewCells looks normal in Xcode but are chopped off when displayed in a simulator. Please see the images below.

Anyone know why this is?

Any help is much appreciated!

Xcode image:

[image]

Simulator image:

[image]

```
class Feed: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}

override open func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    //It will hide the status bar again after dismiss
    UIApplication.shared.isStatusBarHidden = false
}
override open var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell
}
```

Comment: You can use automatic table view cell height or implement `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` delegate method. There are many tutorials.

Comment: Did you set a height for the rows in the tableview's size inspector?

Comment: Have you set proper constraints to the tableView i.e its top should be bottom of your UImageView

Comment: Thank you all for taking time to answer my question. I've tried both methods (coding and changing the inspector) and both have worked perfectly. Again I really appreciate all of your time and effort to help me. Have a G'day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)`. Add a height as per requirement.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, works perfectly. Really appreciate you willing to spend time to help me. Do have a G'day!

Comment: No problem dude...Just helping the community that helped me once :)